# Как вывести ValidationMessage для скрытого поля в Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, c#, mvc

Всем привет. Не могу разобраться с сабжем) Вот есть у меня в модели такое свойство:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле не заполнено")]
public string MyValues { get; set; }
```

В представлении оно добавлено как скрытое поле:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MyValues)
```

В процессе работы с формой в это поле добавляются некоторые значения. Как мне осуществить вывод ErrorMessage для этого поля, если в него ничего не добавлено? Попробовал сделать так:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyValues )
```

но что-то не работает.

Comment: а с точки зрения обычной человеческой логики вы себе это как представляете? "У вас не заполнено поле, которого вы не можете видеть, так как оно скрыто. Заполните его хоть как-нибудь"?

Comment: Я же говорю, значения в это поле добавляются в процессе работы с формой. Путем редактирования некоторых других ее элементов, если хотите)

Comment: так валидируйте те поля, которые являются видимыми и будет вам счастье

Comment: Дело в том, что их нету в модели, а скрытое поле есть.

Comment: Именно для таких случаев и рекомендуется во View использовать ViewModel, а не объект доменной модели.

Comment: У вас валидация происходит на клиенте или на сервере ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы пытаетесь использовать валидацию на стороне клиента, проверьте присутствие подключенных скриптов, для использования "ненавязчивой" валидации:

```
jquery.validate.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
```

* *при отправке формы, должно появиться сообщение (хотя, маловероятно, но возможно, что данное свойство не учитывает поля, кторорые скрыты, с точки зрения здравой логики, см. комментарий на ваш вопрос №1).*

Вы так же можете использовать валидацию на стороне сервера, для этого в методе контроллера необходим следующий код:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.MyValues))
    ModelState.AddModelError("MyValues", "Error: MyValues IsNullOrEmpty.");

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // Field is not empty.
}
```